# Inversion of adverb/adjective and preposition

Tags: prepositions, adverbs, adverb-position

Is one of the following two sentences incorrect ?

"I didn't get good enough a glimpse" (1)

and

"I didn't get a good enough glimpse" (2)

In my native language, the latter seems more natural, but the former sounds better to my "english ear", so I'm a bit conflicted about it, and am not sure what words to look up.

If both are correct, is there a nuance between the two versions ? I can't think of any that would make sense.

If the first version is correct (regardless of the second), in what circumstances should one invert and adverb and a preposition ? (this seems to be related to the adverb "enough" rather than the adjective "good", because "I didn't get good a glimpse" definitely does not sound right - in particular, although this sounds superficially related to the inversion in "how good a glimpse did you get ?", I don't think they actually are)

Answer (score 1):

Typically people say, "I didn't get enough of a look."  I wouldn't use "glimpse" because a *glimpse* is, by definition, quite fleeting (brief, probably incomplete).

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I think the point of the question is not about the specific noun ("glimpse" or "look"), but about the position. So "good enough a look", or "a good enough look"

Comment: @Maxime - Ah, thanks.  Note, "good enough a look" doesn't work, but "I didn't get good enough of a look" and "I didn't get enough of a look."